# Enable/disable layers via command line

Tags: svg, inkscape

I have a script (below) which exports from an svg file to png files of various sizes. This works, but I need more. I need to be able to enable and disable layers before the export.
So, for example, just after the #**Android** line, I need to
enable layer **android** and disable layer **ios**

How can I do this?

```
set -x

# Windows
INKSCAPE="/C/Program Files/Inkscape/inkscape.exe"
OPTS=--export-background-opacity=0

# Note that directories must already exist before exporting to them

SVG=My_Icon.svg
DEST=generated_icons

# Android
"$INKSCAPE" -w36 $OPTS --export-png=$DEST/android/ic_launcher-ldpi.png $SVG
"$INKSCAPE" -w48 $OPTS --export-png=$DEST/android/ic_launcher-mdpi.png $SVG
"$INKSCAPE" -w72 $OPTS --export-png=$DEST/android/ic_launcher-hdpi.png $SVG
"$INKSCAPE" -w96 $OPTS --export-png=$DEST/android/ic_launcher-xhdpi.png $SVG
"$INKSCAPE" -w144 $OPTS --export-png=$DEST/android/ic_launcher-xxhdpi.png $SVG
"$INKSCAPE" -w192 $OPTS --export-png=$DEST/android/ic_launcher-xxxhdpi.png $SVG
"$INKSCAPE" -w512 $OPTS --export-png=$DEST/android/ic_launcher-web.png $SVG

# iOS
"$INKSCAPE" -w57 $OPTS --export-png=$DEST/ios/ios_icon-57.png $SVG
"$INKSCAPE" -w72 $OPTS --export-png=$DEST/ios/ios_icon-72.png $SVG
"$INKSCAPE" -w114 $OPTS --export-png=$DEST/ios/ios_icon-57-2x.png $SVG
"$INKSCAPE" -w144 $OPTS --export-png=$DEST/ios/ios_icon-72-2x.png $SVG
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with a method using `xmlstarlet` to edit the InkScape SVG on the fly before passing it to InkScape itself.

Imagine you have an InkScape SVG with three layers, `SenateBackground`, `Caesar` and `Antonius`, and you only want the combinations `(SenateBackground,Caesar)` and `(SenateBackground,Antonius)`.

This is how such a layer looks in the SVG:

```
<g
 inkscape:label="Caesar"
 id="someID"
 inkscape:groupmode="layer"
 style="display:none"
 sodipodi:insensitive="true"
 transform="...">
```

Just as a side note: In some other SO questions, the tip of querying the layers using `inkscape --query-all <file> | grep "layer"` has come up, at least in my findings this is not reliable, as inkscape does not *always* name the `id="someID"` as `id="layerX"` (which the `grep` looks for). For me, some of the layers simply got group IDs like `g12345`.

To generate the PNG with Caesar in the Senate, the steps are now...

1. Read the SVG/XML
   This can be done with `cat`
2. Pipe it through `xmlstarlet`, showing the senate background
   In my example I handle *every* layer, so I do not have any 
   restrictions like *When modifying the SVG, remember to show/hide
   layer X/Y before saving, the PNG generation script relies on it!*.
3. Pipe it through `xmlstarlet` again, showing Caesar
4. Pipe it through `xmlstarlet` again, hiding Antonius
5. Pipe it to InkScape, creating the PNG
   You have to provide the width/height or DPI as this apparently 
   will not be taken from the settings stored in the file.

Command:

```
cat romanSenate.svg | \
xmlstarlet edit -P -S --update "//*[@inkscape:label='SenateBackground']/@style" -v "display:inline" | \
xmlstarlet edit -P -S --update "//*[@inkscape:label='Caesar']/@style" -v "display:inline" | \
xmlstarlet edit -P -S --update "//*[@inkscape:label='Antonius']/@style" -v "display:none" | \
inkscape -z -e romanSenate.svg.showingCaesar.png -d 300 /dev/stdin
```

`-d 300` specifies the output DPI. We use `/dev/stdin` as input file because InkScape does not handle anything piped to it.

Answer (score 1):

Well a SVG is just an XML so you could conceive a tool that modifies the XML in the way you want, setting the layers in question to in/visible.

That said, there might be **more convenient option**: When converting with Inkscape via CLI you can state the ID of the XML node you want to export along with a flag to not render anything else.

From Inkscape's man page:

> -i, --export-id
>
> The area exported will be defined by the bounding box of the named object. The exported drawing will include the parts of
>   any other objects that fall within this bounding box. The name of a
>   given object can be found by selecting the object from within Inkscape
>   and looking at the XML Editor. (Of course, if you do this, you may as
>   well export using the Export Bitmap dialog.)
>
> -j, --export-id-only
>
> Only the specified object is exported. Must be used with the --export-id option. See above. Can be used with
>   --export-area-canvas and --export-area-page.

For proper reference you can set the IDs of the nodes from within Inkscape.